Removing rows from an array sourced from item in another array
I'm using
$Devices = Get-MgDevice to get the devices from Azure with Graph
$autopilot = Get-MgDeviceManagementWindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentity to get all the autopilot devices
I wish to remove the $autopilot devices from $Devices and I have an $autopilot.AzureActiveDirectoryDeviceId which I can match to an Id/DeviceId (one of those anyway) in the $Devices.
I could loop through $Devices and compare to each $autopilot for the value but I was wondering if there was something a bit more efficient to do the same.
I've seen some $listA = $listA |Where-Object { $listB -notcontains $_.somevalue } stuff but can't seem to find any examples where it's a bit more complex referencing object values. So I'm not sure if I'm struggling with syntax or functionality
these are the 2 sources I'm using
$Devices = 
    Get-MgDevice -top 80 |
    Where-Object {$_.operatingSystem -eq "Windows"} | 
    Select AccountEnabled,ApproximateLastSignInDateTime, DeviceCategory, DeviceId, DeviceOwnership, DeviceVersion, DisplayName, Id

$autopilot = Get-MgDeviceManagementWindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentity

# This is what seems to get me there thanks all 



$Devices =Get-MgDevice -top 100 |Where-Object {$_.operatingSystem -eq "Windows"}| Select AccountEnabled,ApproximateLastSignInDateTime, DeviceCategory, DeviceId, DeviceOwnership, DeviceVersion, DisplayName, Id, IsCompliant, IsManaged, OnPremisesLastSyncDateTime, OnPremisesSyncEnabled,    OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion, ProfileType, RegistrationDateTime ,TrustType, @{Name="CreatedDateTime";Expression={$_.AdditionalProperties.createdDateTime}}, @{Name="EnrollmentProfileName";Expression={$_.AdditionalProperties.enrollmentProfileName}}, @{Name="enrollmentType";Expression={$_.AdditionalProperties.enrollmentType}}, @{Name="isRooted";Expression={$_.AdditionalProperties.isRooted}}, @{Name="managementType";Expression={$_.AdditionalProperties.managementType}}, @{Name="manufacturer";Expression={$_.AdditionalProperties.manufacturer}}, @{Name="model";Expression={$_.AdditionalProperties.model}}

$autopilot = Get-MgDeviceManagementWindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentity -all

$HashDevices = @{}

Foreach ($Device in $Devices)
{
    $HashDevices.add( $Device.DeviceID , $Device )
}


Foreach ($Apilot in $autopilot)
{
    
    if ($HashDevices.ContainsKey($Apilot.AzureActiveDirectoryDeviceId)){
    
        $HashDevices.remove($Apilot.AzureActiveDirectoryDeviceId)
    }
}








You probably want to create a hash table,  see: Looking up entries by property in large collections

Can you show the code you’ve got so far.

I just added the sources I'm using

The call to Get-MgDeviceManagementWindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentity is likely not needed if your intent is to get all devices NOT enrolled. You could just get devices where enrollmentProfileName doesn't start with Windows Autopilot
